# SQL - Can't get around parameter value ask

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to pull together a table which shows the summary of invoice totals by invoice number and customer code. I think I have it mostly down but when I try to summarize the line item prices which would give an invoice total, I get the parameter value input box for the line_price field.

When you go into the table, the first layer of data has invoice number and customer code. From there, you can drill in and you get line item numbers per invoice and the total value per line. I need to sum that total value per line and show it at the customer code and invoice number level.

Below is what I have so far:

```
SELECT CUS_CODE, INV_NUMBER, SUM(LINE_PRICE) AS InvoiceTotal
FROM INVOICE
GROUP BY CUS_CODE, INV_NUMBER;
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'drill in' - exactly how do you do that - subdatasheet? If LINE_PRICE is not in INVOICE table then of course the query cannot see it. Most likely you need to JOIN tables. Are you using Access query designer? Or build a report and use its Sorting & Grouping features with aggregate calcs. This allow display of detail records as well as summary data. But again, most likely need to JOIN tables for report RecordSource.

Answer (score 0):

You must include the subdata, the invoice lines' table, like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    CUS_CODE, INV_NUMBER, SUM(LINE_PRICE) AS InvoiceTotal
FROM 
    INVOICE
INNER JOIN 
    INVOICE_LINE 
    ON INVOICE.ID = INVOICE_LINE.INVOICE_ID
GROUP BY 
    CUS_CODE, INV_NUMBER;
```